# Blueprism Version 6.5 Queue Filter

Tags: blueprism

We have recently upgraded to Blueprism 6.5 but don't seem to be able to filter our queues?
I have tried using exact string matches, wildcards, fragments etc. I have also tried default values available in the drop down. The filter just turns red and nothing happens.

[image]

Comment: Is this all columns you can't filter on or any specifically?

Comment: All, on the jobs, and in the session management I can only filter on prepopulated columns such as resource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Blue Prism Portal it's a version 6.5 bug, should be fixed in version 6.6, see below message from their portal.

> Issues reported since the release of 6.5 have resulted in new development to improve the auto-validation performance when opening processes and objects in studio. Primarily this will benefit environments where objects and processes have large numbers of linked objects and processes. **An additional fix, to ensure that the filters in the Tags and Resource columns in Queue Management are applied, is also in development.
>   These fixes will be made available in 6.6**